# Is IndexedDB encrypted? Is it correct place for private data?

Tags: javascript, encryption, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb, firefox-addon-webextensions

In my web extension I need to store secured data - not a passwords but will be good to not have it in plain text file on disk. `chrome.storage` is not encrypted, cookies is encrypted but for lighter http calls would be nice to not introduce unused overhead, so maybe `IndexedDB` - but neither in [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB-2/#security) nor [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) nor [tag description on StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/indexeddb/info) nor [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_Database_API) is not mentioned - **is it encrypted storage in some browsers**? Can I connect through ssh to the remove desktop and read/copy this database?

Comment: No, its not.  Encrypt the data yourself before saving it?

Comment: Yes, I can encrypt by my code... Why in a comment if you sure that this is an answer? :)

Comment: Encrypting by a constant key doesn't add any additional protection and if the data is hacked, the attacker should already have the ability to decode it.

Comment: Yes, but anyway this is +1 for security.

Comment: Define "secured". Whom are you trying to "protect" that data *from*? Who is and isn't supposed to see that data?

Comment: Would be nice to have some protection against activity on the computer of user - some malicious that can read data from disk, or attacker through ssh. This data is only for a user and installed web extension that operates this data.

Comment: Malware on the user's system can do anything the user can do. If the user has access to the data in some way (and they usually do), then so does malware. It's virtually impossible to protect against running on a malicious system.

Comment: @deceze The main use case is protecting the DB files stored in the file system when the system is compromised later, independent of running the app. You may not run the app but the files are there. Attacks against the file system by checking contents of files, not attacks against the running web app. Obviously the latter is very hard or impossibel to achieve by encrypting the IndexedDB data, but that's not the point. What about somebody steals the laptop? If the app is secure they can't use it - but if the data can be read directly... so you encrypt it to make file level access harmless.

Comment: ...Furthermore, if the objection to my argument is "if they have the computer they have the key" -- not if you don't store the key in any form. It can be calculated, or obtained from the server (it can be one constructed purely by the server-side, making the stored data available for reading only when the app is successfully started and successfully communicated with the server-side. Then there won't be a key stored on the system when the app is not running.

Answer (score -4):

1) I think that cookies are enough security - because I found that `origin` of extension is like `chrome-extension://jjoiglhhlajadogodcpfifnceisdfsdfsf` so other domains will receive these cookies only with explicit including of the cookies like:

```
fetch('http://httpbin.org/get', {'credentials': 'include'})
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => console.log(r))
```

2) Encrypt data on `chrome.storage.sync` or inside `IndexedDB`.